# laravel 7 join() and first() don't work together

Tags: sql, laravel, join

I want to select information from two tables at the same time using join and first() but I get an error saying :

```
    TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of 
    the type string or null, object given,
```

this what I am doing :

```
    public function getResult(Request $req){
       $result= DB::table('form')
       ->select('form.*', 'test.*')
       ->join('test','test.form_id' , '=', 'form.id' )
       ->where('test.id',$req->id)
       ->first();

       return $result;
}
```

NB: it is working when I use get() but I only need the first selected one

can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Would using a limit and get work? `->limit(1)->get()` instead of the `->first()`

Comment: limit(1)  get me the result like [{......}] but I want something like {........}

Answer (score 0):

If I use a `leftJoin()`, `first()` is working for me, maybe you could try this out?

**@edit**

You should be able to use `->get()-first()`